# Looking for an efficient way to solve a fractional problem (affine function over euclidean norm )

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-programming, generalized-linear-fractional

While working on optimization issues I encountered the following problem:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    {\displaystyle \sup_{z\in\mathbb{R}^{m}}} &\frac{ \langle c,z \rangle + \rho}{ \left\|B z\right\|}  \\
     \mbox{s. t} & Az\leq b\\
     & \langle f,z\rangle =1.
\end{array} \right.$$
where $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ is the Euclidean norm. I know that this is a fractional problem, and I know that the easiest fractional problems to solve are those that are a quotient of two affine functions. However, this problem is not of that type. I have tried to solve it in Matlab with fmincon, but it takes too long to find a solution. My intention is to know if there is a more efficient way to solve this problem. The reason for this posting is to ask you for suggestions on how to deal with this problem.

Comment: Perhaps fix $||Bz||=c$ which might be easier to solve for fixed c, and then do a line search over c.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4663551/looking-for-an-efficient-way-to-solve-a-fractional-problem-affine-function-over

Comment: It is a Sharpe-ratio type issue, you can formulate it as SOCP by homogenizing, for instance https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#maximizing-the-sharpe-ratio  and https://themosekblog.blogspot.com/2020/10/sharpe-ratio-derivation-and-fusion-model.html

Comment: @Michal Adamaszekk You should make your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Michal Adamaszek Some people on this forum and math SE don't like link only. answers because they rot, whereas on mathoverflow SE they are acceptable and common. I suggest just copy and pasting material from the links, which I presume you wrote anyway, and provide the links.